# Which two groups are isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Which of the two following groups are isomorphic?

$C_{12} \times C_{35} \times C_{45}$

$C_{10} \times C_{30} \times C_{63}$

$C_{20} \times C_{21} \times C_{45}$

$C_{14} \times C_{18} \times C_{75}$

I know if two groups are isomorphic, they are bijective and the mapping sends products to products.

Can someone please give a hint so I can have an attempt. They can be broken down into this (I think):

$C_3 \times C_4 \times C_7 \times C_5 \times C_{5} \times C_9$

$C_5 \times C_2 \times C_3 \times C_{5} \times C_2 \times C_9 \times C_7 $

$C_5 \times C_4 \times C_7 \times C_3 \times C_{9} \times C_5$

$C_7 \times C_2 \times C_9 \times C_2  \times C_{25} \times C_3$

Comment: Break them apart as much as possible. E.g. $C_{12}\cong C_3\times C_4$. Then compare $p$-primary parts.

Comment: @anon OK can I just ask, with $C_4$, can we break this to $C_2 \times C_2$? I am asking because it breaks into identical ones

Comment: No, $C_4$ and $C_2\times C_2$ are not the same. (Be sure you know how to *prove* that they're not the same.) According to Sun-Ze (better known as the Chinese Remainder Theorem), $C_{nm}\cong C_n\times C_m$ whenever $n$ and $m$ are relatively prime. Have you ever came across that fact before? But they're never the same when $n$ and $m$ share a nontrivial factor. Also, have you seen the fundamental theorem of finite abelian groups yet?

Comment: @anon OK so is that for general, if $x=n^2$, then $C_x$ is not the same as $C_n \times C_n$? Or is it just for $2$?

Comment: I've basically just answered that question. Make sure you understand my comment fully.

Comment: @anon Would the answer be that the first and third are isomorphic? Because $C_{12} \times C_{35}= C_4 \times C_3 \times C_7 \times C_5$ and $C_{20} \times C_{21}$ equals the same but in a different order. And they both have $C_{45}$ which should not be broken down since the factors of $45$ include a $5$ which is a common factor to $35$ from the first one and $20$ from the second.

Comment: @snowman $C_{45}$ can be broken down into $C_5 \times C_9$.  Your reasoning is wrong: the factors of $35$ and $20$ are completely irrelevant to whether it is possible to rewrite $C_{45}$ as $C_5 \times C_9$ (however, there is no need to do so if it is already clear the two groups are equivalent without breaking it down).

Comment: How about this: edit your question with your attempt to break down the groups as much as possible. (Then you can get upvotes for having show your work, too.) After that we can tell you if you've broken them down correctly. And after *that* you can decide which ones are isomorphic or not and why.

Comment: @anon OK edited. Decomposed them, are they correct?

Comment: $C_6, C_{10}, C_{15}, C_{45}$ can be broken down further.

Comment: @Slade OK it should all be good now right?

Comment: Your $C_{18}$ and $C_{75}$ in the last example are broken apart incorrectly.

Comment: @anon any better now? If so, I really don't understand why..............

Comment: Yep! Now it's perfect. Next, compare $p$-primary parts. For example, all four groups have $3$-primary part $C_3\times C_9$. (You just collect all parts whose elements have $p$-power order.) Two finite abelian groups are isomorphic if they have the same $p$-primary parts for each prime $p$. If two finite abelian groups have different $p$-primary parts for any prime $p$, then they are not isomorphic. (Note, two direct products of cyclic groups of $p$-power order are isomorphic if and only if they have the same multiset of orders, e.g. $C_2\times C_2$ would correspond to the multiset $\{2,2\}$.)

Comment: @anon so by p-power order, you mean like $C_3=\{1,i,-i\}$ has elements that do not have p-power order because 1 has order 1, i has order 4 (and 4 is not a prime) and -i has order 2?

Comment: No. By "$p$-power order" I mean order which is a power of $p$. Every element of $C_3$ has order $1$ or $3$, and every element of $C_9$ has order $1$ or $3$ or $9$. These numbers are all powers of $3$. Note that $C_3$ is certainly not $\{1,i,-i\}$. First of all, it's impossible for a group of odd order to have elements with even order (except the identity), so in particular $C_3$ cannot have elements of order $4$. Secondly, $\{1,i,-i\}$ is not a group. It is not closed under multiplication! (And in the group $\{1,-1,i,-i\}\cong C_4$, the element $-i$ has order $4$, not order $2$.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first and third groups are isomorphic,as re-arranging the order of a product of groups gives an isomorphic product. The fourth group has an element with order 25 and the other groups don't.The first group has an element of order 4, but the second group doesn't.

Comment: quick question about orders, for $C_n$, does that mean all elements in this has order $n$ or at max $n$? I am pretty sure all elements have order at max $n$. So when you say "The first group has an element of order 4, but the second group doesn't", how do you know that in the second group, that (say) $C_7$ doesn't have an element of order 4?

Comment: In a finite group with n members ,the order of a member must be a divisor of n. This is a basic theorem. Not hard to prove.